# AdjustWindowRect() off by 7 pixels?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

```
int width=640, height=480;
RECT rect{0,0,width,height};
const DWORD style = WS_VISIBLE|WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW;
AdjustWindowRect(&rect,style,false);
auto hwnd = CreateWindowA("listbox","test",style,CW_USEDEFAULT,CW_USEDEFAULT,rect.right-rect.left,rect.bottom-rect.top,nullptr,nullptr,nullptr,nullptr);
```

The client rectangle is 640x473. What did I do wrong?

Comment: you not take to account extended window styles ( `WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE`) you need use `CreateWindowExW` only to direct set extended window styles. and if you want use not 0 here - use `AdjustWindowRectEx`

Comment: @WeatherVane: No. [`RECT`s are endpoint-exclusive](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040218-00/?p=40563).

Comment: @RbMm Using Ex variants with WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE in both gives the same result.

Comment: you need use the same style in `AdjustWindowRectEx` and `CreateWindowExW`

Comment: and main - "listbox" default window procedure change it size and position after window become visible - try create window without `WS_VISIBLE`, gey it client rect size, than show it and again check size

Comment: concrete for listbox you need use `LBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT` style if you want exactly size

Comment: @RbMm could you please post `LBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT` as an answer so I can accept it? And thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you use List Box control the result height is depend from  [`LBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775149(v=vs.85).aspx) style:

> Specifies that the size of the list box is exactly the size specified
>   by the application when it created the list box. Normally, the system
>   sizes a list box so that the list box does not display partial items.

so without this style, default List Box window procedure resize window, for not display partial items